# Can I post ajax without .serialize and retrieve the posted data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp-classic

If I'm posting ajax like the following code snippet illustrates, and want to have the post url / page (in this case, posted.asp) retrieve data from the json post, what do I use to access / retrieve the data?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "posted.asp",          data: { Grades: studentGradesArray },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

I've tried

```
<%= request.form("Grades") %>
```

and

```
<% request.querystring("Grades") %>
```

Another question:  Is it necessary to stringify the json similar to this, which I've also tried:

```
url: "posted.asp", data: JSON.stringify({ Grades: studentGradesArray }),
```

Basically what Im trying to do is use classic asp / vbscript to access incoming (ajax POSTed JSON) data  and then be able to use the data server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `contentType` option. The default is to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, and this is what `request.form()` expects.